# How to pass params to dynamic component in React?

Tags: reactjs

Let's imagine we have a home page which includes a component `A`, and pass a component `B` to that A as a `prop` .
Now , inside the `A` , How can I pass params to the sent `B` ?

**Home Page**

```
return(
    <A myChild={<B>} />
)
```

**Component B**

```
return(
    <div>Welcome from B !</div>
)
```

**Component A**

```
//I get B successfully !

<div>{this.props.myChild}</div>
```

But How can I here pass a param to `this.props.myChild` ?
Something like `const MyB={this.props.myChild};` and `<MyB whatEver={'abc'} />` so the `B` becomes :

```
return(
    <div>Welcome from B ! {this.props.whatEver}</div>
)
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the class/function (`B`) as a prop rather than an instance of that class/function (`<B>`). Then allow the `A` component to call and render `B` and props can be passed as usual.

So for example you would have:

**Home Page**

```js
return(
    <A MyChild={ B } />
)
```

**Component A**

```js
const { MyChild } = this.props;
const whatEver = "Hello";
return (
    <MyChild whatEver={ whatEver }/>
)
```

**Component B**

```js
return(
    <div>Welcome from B ! {this.props.whatEver}</div>
)
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks . Worked for me as `const MyChild = this.props.MyChild;`

Answer (score 0):

you should pass any component as children and render children in parent compnent or you can use [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) technique
Home Page

```
<A>
  <B whatEver={'abc'} />
</A>
```

Component A

```
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
```

Component B

```
<div>Welcome from B ! {this.props.whatEver}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks . But it's not the case . `abc` is simply a data exists only inside component `A` and it couldn't be in the `HomePage` . So I should send `B` as a param to `A` via `HomePage`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, the following snippet will work only if `MyChild` prop is capitalised (so, `myChild` from your question will not work).

```
const { MyChild } = this.props;
const whatEver = "Hello";
return (
    <MyChild whatEver={ whatEver }/>
)
```

This exact code `<MyChild whatEver={ whatEver }/>` gets rewritten into `React.createElement` function when JSX is parsed. So if you want to keep your props lower cased (e.g. `component`) then you can call `createElement` yourself:

```
const { component } = this.props;
const props = {whatEver: "Hello"};
return React.createElement(component, props);
```

or in JSX:

```
// ...
return (
  <div>
    {React.createElement(component, props)}
  </div>
);
```